# Merging landsat 8 tiff images in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am working with the following ten landsat 8 images:

```
LC81340412016058LGN00
LC81350412016065LGN00
LC81350422016001LGN00
LC81360412015341LGN00
LC81360422016216LGN00
LC81360432016216LGN00
LC81370412015316LGN00
LC81370422015364LGN00
LC81380412016086LGN00
LC81380422016214LGN00
```

When I opened these images in QGIS with the supporting shapefiles it covered the entire state of Assam (in India).
But After I tried to merge them using QGIS Raster tool the merged image did not cover the entire state. Only a small part of Assam was shown in the QGIS in the merged image.

Before merging

[image: landsat 8 images covering entire Assam]

Before merging in QGIS

[image]

after merging in QGIS

Comment: What exactly are you doing step by step?

Comment: After clipping the lansat 8 images with shapefiles I want to do vegetation mapping and also use NDVI, NDWI etc.

Comment: First I would mosaic and then clip all the images for further processing

Comment: Just an idea: did you keep `Place each input file into a seperate band` merge option **unchecked**? If you checked it, your images are merged into one with many bands. Check metadata of created layer.

Comment: Yes it was unchecked by default and I kept it as such. What will I get in the metadata of the created layer

Comment: @ASalimKhan thought about number of bands, can you edit your question and provide more information, for exaple screenshot your setting of merge window?

Comment: Seems like you have an Alpha value, which is not "used" for merging. You need to create an Alpha Band from that value.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge them together using the QGIS Merge tool for rasters, see this tutorial: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/raster_mosaicing_and_clipping.html

[image]

Comment: I think OP used this tool but he is struggling whit its output.

Comment: I have already tried this way but the output is not coming. The problem is somewhere else

Comment: do I have to use <build virtual raster> before merging?

Comment: No, @ASalimKhan, you don't. Just use the QGIS tool. You could show the configuration of the tool?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like when merging you lose the alpha information, because you have none or it's only set as Alpha value. Like that the areas surrounding your Images overlap the others, which results in black color.

You need to create an Alpha Band from that value for **each** individual raster image. Then merging should work.

With QGIS you can do that with the Tool: Raster -> Analysis-> Near Black

Set the in- and output file accordingly and then click the edit button and add "-setalpha" like in the Screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I am not getting the same 'Near black' display in Windows 10 QGIS as u are showing here.

Comment: the edit portions reads like this: nearblack -o "E:/GIS Data/landsat8_Data/Assam_landsat8/Assam_merged.tif"
where do I put -setalpha- o

Comment: You can put it before the -o

Comment: there are more than 40 tiff images of different bands. QGIS is taking only one image at a time. Is there a way to load all the images for setting alpha

Comment: After I tried to do this, QGIS returned the following 
"The process failed to start. 
Either the invoked program is missing, or you may have insufficient permission to invoke the program"

Comment: you might to write `nearblack.exe [...]`, I'm not aware about Windows specific things.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) utility from [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) library. E.g. `gdalwarp $(list_of_tiffs) merged.tif`.

Comment: The question is about QGIS.

Comment: Sorry I have never used gdalwarp. Plz do tell me if this can be done in QGIS

Comment: @Dmitriy point to command line use of GDAL. If you are using *merge* from raster menu in QGIS, you exactly use GDAL - `gdal_merge.py` (you can see the final command at bottom of merge window)

Comment: plz send a screen shot of how to use gdalwrap for mosaicing and clipping.

Comment: I am using ten tiff images each containing 11 bands 30 m resolution. file sizes are very large. may be there is a bug coming up in QGIS.