# Merging two Landsat TIFF file of same band in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, merge, landsat, band

I've been wanting to merge two TIFF files of same band (this case it will be B1 in Landsat). I have followed tutorials which I came across online, but none of them seems to work. Generally, raster > miscellaneous > merge is the procedure. But it only ends up showing one TIFF file. Should I create a virtual raster and then try? Or maybe it's not possible to merge any single band (e.g. B1,B2 etc.)?

Also please tell me if I'm using the right output file type. 
Here are few screenshot of the problem: [image]
[image]
[image]
(In the last screenshot, i clipped the raster with a shapefile to check whether it merged properly.)

This is  kind of similar to my problem which was posted here earlier but no possible solution came out of it: [Merging landsat 8 tiff images in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230910/merging-landsat-8-tiff-images-in-qgis)

Comment: Please edit your question so it contains the images instead of linking to them, thank you. Also try to use paragraphs to make it better readable, thank you. Last but not least also provide a screenshot of the dialogue window when you're merging the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **Merge** tool for each band of Landsat scene, make sure to give **0** into `Input pixel value to treat as "nodata"` option.

[image]

Set to `0`:

[image]

Leaving the option as default `Not set`:

[image]

Comment: i just tried what you just mentioned but now it looks like this : https://imgur.com/a/ASBRSS4

Comment: @asheef_ik If you mean the position of these images (fully apart) is the issue, it is unrelated with the process. Let me suggest another tool (my preferred one) in SAGA.

Answer (score 2):

If you have trouble with Merge tool, then the second option (my preferred one) would be SAGA **Mosaic Raster layers** tool.

Find it in QGIS Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Raster tools.

[image]

- Make sure `Interpolation` set to `Nearest Neighbor`. You don't want to change the value by interpolation.
- Overlapping option can be anything. (`feathering` is just my suggestion).

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for taking efforts to solve the problem, i've used saga raster tool this time, but the problem persists, only one of the raster is shown after being merged : https://imgur.com/a/hnvK9KI

Comment: @asheef_ik Thanks for additional info. It seems you have two Landsat8 images over path 137, 138 and row 045... is it near Bangladesh coastline? I suspect western image is on UTM45N while the eastern one is on UTM46N. Can you reproject one of them to put them on the same CRS?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, it worked this time. There has been problem with projection all along. It looks finely merged now: https://imgur.com/a/xIA2rf4

Comment: Thanks @asheef_ik for the feedback. Glad it worked :)

Comment: i would be bothering you again i'm afraid. although it worked that time, i am having difficulties with the merging tool now. could you take look at these images and tell me what's wrong ? I'm using the "set crs" options to change projections and raster merging tool to merge them. I am also adding the google earth images of the forest that i am willing to get. Thank you.  https://imgur.com/a/jg7hmzr

Comment: Hi @asheef_ik To reproject one of two rasters, I recommend to use **Warp (reproject)** tool, which is under `Raster > Projections` menu. You might have used `assign` or `set` crs tools, these tools do not change crs (they do set crs information if it is missing, though).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's still not merging, could you check the descriptions and the picture ? should i try re-projecting them in UTM 46N instead ? https://imgur.com/a/us45vG6

Comment: @asheef_ik Sorry for this late reply. It seems you have reprojected successfully. As these images are on different UTM zones, please reproject only one of them. I would suggest the eastern one (which is currently on UTM 46N) to be reprojected to UTM 45N. It makes your project crs set to UTM 45N.

Comment: initially both rasters are in UTM 45N, unfortunately i didn't quite get what you meant to say. This a screenshot of the files right after i added them to qgis : https://imgur.com/a/xBon4ot

Comment: so i had to change CRS of the western one to UTM 46N, then reproject it to UTM 45N and finally used merged tool which merged them .

Comment: @asheef_ik I mistook you were talking about the same set you had worked on previously. This time, however, do you think they should be contiguous?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102987/discussion-between-asheef-ik-and-kazuhito).

Comment: hello there, do you happen to know how to generate histograms of NDVI in qgis ? i am planning to make histograms like those mentioned in this article : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050915019444 . It seems they have used SAGA GIS for this purpose; whereas i am planning to do the same in qgis.

Comment: @asheef_ik Have you tried `Raster layer histogram` tool in the `Processing Toolbox > Graphics` ?

Comment: yes i did, however saga gis takes significantly less time to generate histogram than QGIS. One more question, as you know downloading Landsat data comes with metadata file. How can i possibly get or generate such metadata file once i have merged two TIF files ?

Comment: @asheef_ik Not automatically, but you can update metadata yourself by any text editors.

Comment: could you check this out:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347776/producing-vegetation-indices-maps-and-histogram-using-saga-gis